# How to set srcPaths in Gradle to specific subdirectory within collection of subdirectories

Tags: gradle

I'm attempting to massage an existing open-source library from Github that was originally created (and is currently maintained as) a very, very large and complex set of Eclipse projects into something that can be directly built within Android Studio using Gradle.

The projects are in this repo: https://github.com/unidata/awips2-core

Its dependencies are in this repo: https://github.com/unidata/awips2-core-foss

The awips2-core repo has the following directory structure:

```
./awips2-core/common/
./awips2-core/edex/
./awips2-core/features/
.awips2-core/viz/
```

Those four directories each contain the top-level directories for multiple projects, with names like "com.raytheon.uf.common.util"

Those directories have the following contents (using the 'util' project as an example):

```
META-INF
src  (contains ./com/raytheon/uf/common/util/*.java)
tests (same as src)
.classpath
.project
build.properites
com.raytheon.uf.common.util.ecl
```

I created the Android Studio project with a minimal Activity and module named 'app' in c:\src\awips2core-android, then proceeded to check out the two Git repos into subdirectories of the project's root directory:

```
cd \src\awips2core-android
git clone https://github.com/unidata/awips2-core
git clone https://github.com/unidata/awips2-core-foss
```

I then modified settings.gradle:

```
include ':awips2core'
include ':app'

project(':awips2core').projectDir = new File('./awips2-core')
```

... and added /src/awips2core-android/awips2-core/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['common/com.raytheon.uf.common.util/src', 'common/com.raytheon.uf.common.wxmath/src']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: '../awips2-core-foss')
}
```

This works.

#### The problem:

I have another 41 srcDirs under common/, and almost a hundred when you include the ones under edex/, features/, and viz/.

What I'd LIKE to do is add them programmatically, instead of one by one. In Java terms, something like:

```
List<File> srcPaths = new ArrayList<File>();
String[] paths =  {"common", "features", "edex", "viz"};
for(String subdir : paths) {
    // the path "c:/src/awips2core-android/awips2-core" would be implied by the project's definition in gradle.settings
    File projDir = new File("c:/src/awips2core-android/awips2-core", subdir);
    File[] subprojectDirs = projDir.listFiles();
    for (File dir : subprojectDirs)
        srcPaths.add(new File(dir, "src"));
}

// now, set set Gradle's srcDirs to srcPaths' elements...
```

So... **How would I implement this in Groovy for Gradle, or what's the *proper* way to achieve this using Gradle?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a multi-project build: https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/

I would either put everything under the same root or put the foss into a separate project create the jar file and publish to somewhere(mavenLocal for test) and create a multi-project from the awips2-core project.

**update**

The great thing with gradle that the build files are code too.

I didn't try your java code, but that should work more or less to collect the directories as it is valid in groovy too. Once you've collected the directories into a collection(srcDirs is a Set according to the gradle documentation), then you can use that in the sourceSets block.

I would write something along this using streams:

```
def srcPaths = ["common", "features", "edex", "viz"].stream()
        .map { new File(projectDir, it) }
        .flatMap { it.listFiles().toList().stream() }
        .map { new File(it, "src") }
        .toSet()

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = srcPaths
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the rewritten question... I reworked the project structure and think I'm stumbling in the right general direction (since I got a baby step to work by explicitly specifying two of the Eclipse subprojects for srcPaths), but now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to actually generate srcPaths programmatically using Groovy syntax for ALL of the subdirectories.